# How do I add missing YAML header info to .rmd R Markdown file within a script?

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm developing a workflow where I

1. collaboratively work on a Google Doc, which is then
2. downloaded as .docx with the googledrive package,
3. converted to .rmd with rmarkdown:pandoc_convert(),
4. styling and logo applied and
5. rendered as .html & PDF for distribution.

I'm currently getting hung up at step 3, when the .rmd file does not have a header.

```
 pandoc_convert("example.docx", "markdown", output = "out.Rmd")
```

How can I inject YAML from another file within the workflow script?
e.g. this header:

```
---
  title: "Title1"    
  html_document:
  number_sections: yes
  self_contained: yes
  toc: yes
  toc_depth: 3
  toc_float: yes
---
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your header is in `header.yaml`.  Then simply read the two files and write them out as one:

```
fulltext <- c(readLines("header.yaml"), readLines("out.Rmd"))
writeLines(fullText, "out2.Rmd")
```

Of course, you could also put the header into a string variable instead of reading it from a file, e.g.

```
header <- '---
  title: "Title1"    
  html_document:
  number_sections: yes
  self_contained: yes
  toc: yes
  toc_depth: 3
  toc_float: yes
---'
fulltext <- c(header, readLines("out.Rmd"))
writeLines(fullText, "out2.Rmd")
```

Comment: YES! Thank you, I knew it was easy but haven't used read/writeLines before.